# VS Code Dart debug console hijacks focus from Find Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

While developing in Flutter with the debug console open, I can no longer use the in-file find function properly using the default keyboard shortcuts. *Ctrl+F* still opens up the Find Widget and I can type inside it, but *Enter* and *Shift+Enter* no longer perform **Find Next** and **Find Previous**, respectively. I'm also not able to close the search bar with *Escape*. The same goes for the replace bar. Once I close/minimize the debug console, however, everything is back to normal.
I couldn't find any keyboard shortcuts specific to the debug console that may be overriding the find widget shortcuts. Also, all find widget shortcuts are set to default.

Comment: sounds like the dart extension hijacks keyboard shortcuts, sounds like a github issue

Comment: It's unrelated to the Dart extension, this is default VS Code behaviour :( I copied the VS Code response into an answer for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You've likely seen this (since its your GH issue), but for anyone else coming across this - the VS Code team responded on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83829#issuecomment-554387781):

> This is as designed, since the cmd + f focused the debug console and you can start typing to filter.
>   I understand this might not be the optimal behavior now but we are looking into improving the find in the debug console, thus cmd + f will also in the future not open the editor find widget.

If you unset the `repl.action.filter` keybinding, this should prevent this from happening.